# Did the Unity Team fix that "generics handling" bug back in 2008?

Tags: c#, unity-container, ioc-container

At my level of experience with Unity it might be faster to ask whether the "generics handling" bug acknowledged by [ctavares back in 2008](http://unity.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=30292) was fixed in a public release.

Here was the problem (which might be my problem today):

> Hi,
>
> I get an exception when using ....
>
> container.RegisterType(typeof(IDictionary<,>),
>   typeof(Dictionary<,>));
>
> The exception is...
>
> "Resolution of the dependency failed,
>   type = \"IDictionary`2\", name = \"\".
>   Exception message is: The current
>   build operation (build key Build
>   Key[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String],
>   null]) failed: The current build
>   operation (build key Build
>   Key[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String],
>   null]) failed: The type Dictionary`2
>   has multiple constructors of length
>   2. Unable to disambiguate.
>
> When I attempt...
>
> IDictionary
>   myExampleDictionary =
>   container.Resolve>();

Here was the moderated response:

> There are no books that'll help, Unity is a little too new for publishers to have caught up yet.
>
> Unfortunately, you've run into a bug in our generics handling. This is currently fixed in our internal version, but it'll be a little while before we can get the bits out. In the meantime, as a workaround you could do something like this instead:
>
> public class WorkaroundDictionary : Dictionary
>   {
>      public WorkaroundDictionary() { }
>   }
>
> container.RegisterType(typeof(IDictionary<,>),typeof(WorkaroundDictionary<,>));
>
> The WorkaroundDictionary only has the default constructor so it'll inject no problem. Since the rest of your app is written in terms of IDictionary, when we get the fixed version done you can just replace the registration with the real Dictionary class, throw out the workaround, and everything will still just work.
>
> Sorry about the bug, it'll be fixed soon!

Comment: Best way is going to be to just test it.

Comment: **fastest** way to find out is to test it - and then answer your own question.

Comment: Tom and Sky your assumptions are idealistic: consider the possibility that I am getting errors in code right now that are similar to this 2008 problem---this effectively means that my "tests" have run. Now, the fine point is that are my errors due to this 2008 bug or is it something else?

I assume few of our "bright minds" will actually consider this possibility. So let's watch how far Jeff and the boys will let my points drop as this question gets voted down by the "wisdom" of the crowd.

Comment: it would be better for you to just post the issue you are having so we can duplicate it, see how it is happening, and then let you know if it is something you are doing or if it seems to be unity.  Rather than asking if a 2 year old bug was fixed or not.

Comment: @rasx - I don't think my assumption is idealistic at all. Your "tests" are apparently faulty or lacking. If I have breakage or need to write workarounds due to a bug in a dependency I write a test specifically for that and expect an exception. When that test fails I know that either the dependant bug has been fixed or another has been introduced that requires attention. Focus your tests.

Comment: Sky, it sounds like you can maintain *complete* test coverage for an exception. Excellent work! Maybe someday I'll learn how to do that.

Comment: @rasx - it has nothing to do with the level of coverage. it is about having a test targeting the known bug. apparently what you are saying is that you have a bunch of test that are failing and you are having a hard time figuring out if it is because a bug in unity has been fixed? Well if you had a test named 'Expecting_exception_from_Unity_bug()' or some such in your tests, you could  ignore all of the other noise and know if the bug in unity has changed and then determine whether all the other failures are related to that particular bug.

Comment: @rasx Try getting off your high horse and treating the users here with a little respect - They're giving up their time to try and help you. The least you could do is show a little civility.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Unity Team:

> Just wanted to let folks know we've
>   released the bits that have the
>   generics fixes in them. Take a look
>   and let us know what you think. It's
>   checked into codeplex source control.

You may need to get the latest source and build yourself (2.x) as the bug fix may not have been packaged yet.

Comment: When I run container.`RegisterType(typeof(IDictionary<,>), typeof(Dictionary<,>));` I do *not* get an exception. This must mean the bug is fixed! Wow, why did I ask the question in the first place? [Mean-spirited sarcasm here until actual question is dignified with an answer.]

Comment: I am not exactly sure what else you are expecting.  The unity team says that the bug was fixed in the source, i suggested that if you are still seeing it to get the latest source and see if it still exists.